# Не могу правильно сделать уведомления в android

Tags: android, service, уведомления

Добрый день!

Имеется дата, когда пользователю необходимо напомнить о чем-либо. Напоминать надо за 3 дня, 3 раза в день (утром, днем и вечером). После того, как дата прошла, генерируется другая дата (через месяц). И так по циклу.

Я смог своими силами настроить так, чтобы при запуске сервиса (Service) запускалось уведомление (Notifications), но никак не могу обдумать цикл так, чтобы он делал это за 3 дня 3 раза в день и какие инструменты лучше использовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сервис тут не нужен.

Вам нужно:

1. AlarmManager
2. Его настроить на посылку сообщения ресиверу в нужное время.
3. Ресивер сей надо прописать в манифесте и описать в проекте отдельным файлом-классом.
4. В ресивере отображать уведомление

Вот тут есть весь нужный код: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/534643/17609

Comment: AlarmManager не уничтожается при выключении телефона или же при нехватке памяти?

Comment: Не должен......

Comment: В интернете пишут, что да. Может лучше создать сервис, в манифесте прописать, чтобы он прогружался после перезагрузки телефона и в моменте прогрузки генерировал необходимые даты и создавал по ним AlarmManager?

Comment: @АрсенШогенов, момент перезагрузки принимается ресивером. Какой смысл запускать из него сервис, если можно и так алармы поставить?

Comment: Генерируются даты, скажем это график платежей. Запланируем AlarmManager так, чтобы в те даты программа посылала ответ ресиверу. Закрываем приложение. Потом пользователь меняет что-то в приложении, генерируются другие даты, задачи, которые пользователь запланировал необходимо отменить, а затем запланировать еще раз по другим датам. Чтобы отменить задачи, нужно знать pendingIntent, который уничтожается вместе с активити. А пока Service живой, он может хранить pendingIntent, когда разрушается Service в OnDestroy отменяем всё, и в StartCommand генерируем заново. Правильно или?

Comment: @АрсенШогенов, вам ничто не мешает отменить ранее заданные Alarm-ы через создание идентичного PenginIntent, с последующей задачей новых. AlarmManager будет надёжнее и не будет отжирать батарею юзера постоянно вися в фоне.

Comment: Благодарю за идею! Я понял