# Как реализовать циклический вызов метода раз в 10 минут?

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-alarm-manager

Вопрос относительно `Service`: пытаюсь реализовать процесс, который должен запускаться раз в 10 минут. Создал для этого отдельный метод. Прописал *Cлужбу* в `AndroidManifest.xml`, создал отдельный класс для `Service`. На данный момент *Cлужба* выполняется при запуске приложения и продолжает работать после завершения работы приложения. Но сейчас этот процесс запускается единожды. Метод выполняется в отдельном `Thread`'e в `onStartCommand()`. То есть сама *Cлужба* работает как надо, но вот выполнение метода нужно поставить в бесконечный цикл (с периодичностью 10 минут) до тех пор, пока в приложении пользователь не остановит *Cлужбу*.

Было бы здорово, если бы кто-то привел пример реализации запуска метода с периодичностью в 10 минут.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вам не нужен в данном случае сервис. Вам нужен AlarmManager

```
public static void setAlarm(Context ctx)
{
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) ctx.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intentToTimerReceiver = new Intent(ctx.getApplicationContext(), ReceiverTimer.class);
    intentToTimerReceiver.setAction("someAction");

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            ctx.getApplicationContext(),
            0,
            intentToTimerReceiver,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    int period10Minutes = 10;
    long periodInMiliseconds = periodInMinutes * 60 * 1000;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    {
        am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, periodInMiliseconds, periodInMiliseconds, pendingIntent);
    }
    else
    {
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, periodInMiliseconds, periodInMiliseconds, pendingIntent);
    }
}

private static void cancelAlarm(Context ctx)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "cancelAlarm");
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) ctx.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intentToTimerReceiver = new Intent(ctx.getApplicationContext(), ReceiverTimer.class);
    intentToTimerReceiver.setAction("someAction");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx.getApplicationContext(), 0,
            intentToTimerReceiver,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    am.cancel(pendingIntent);
    pendingIntent.cancel();
}
```

После его установки будет вызван описанный в ресивере и в отдельном классе ReceiverTimer, в коем вам и надо выполнять ваш периодический код

Ресивер:

```
public class ReceiverTimer extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.d(LOG, "onReceive " + intent.getAction());
    }
}
```

Манифест:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
     ...>

    <application
        ...>
        <receiver
            android:name=".receiver.ReceiverTimer"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="someAction"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Весьма признателен за помощь! Видимо, так и поступлю. Попрошу вас еще немного пояснить один момент: в моем методе, который нужно периодически запускать, - получаю 2 значения (int). Одно из них понадобится при следующем запуске метода для проведения сравнения с новым полученным значением. Как в этом случае лучше всего поступить?

Comment: @Владимир, думаю вполне нормально будет записать его в SharedPreferences

Comment: Понял. Благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

С той ж целью можно использовать `Timer`:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Timer mTimer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        mTimer = new Timer();
        startAlarm();
    }

    private void startAlarm() {

        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                                       @Override
                                       public void run() {

                                       //Тут отработка метода в отдельном потоке;

                                           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void run() {

                                               //Тут выход в UI если нужно;

                                               }
                                           });
                                       }
                                   }
                , 0        // Это задержка старта, сейчас 0;
                , 600000); // Это Ваш период в 10 минут;
    }

    private void cancelTimer() {

        if (mTimer != null) {
            mTimer.cancel();
            mTimer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Интересно, а каждые 5 секунд прокатит или система не позволит из-за экономии батареи?

Comment: @ЛЕО, я этот таймер использую в приложении для отправки запросов на сервер. Проверяю подтвердил ли пользователь регистрацию на сайте. Делаю запросы каждые 5 секунд. Вроде ничего не валится. Хотя я пробовал только на Xiaomi RedMi Note 4X c 3/32. Так что тут уж не буду ничего утверждать.

Comment: V.March, А в сервисе не пробовали такое?

Comment: Та как то не было необходимости держать столь долгоиграющий процесс. Мне в данном случае было необходимо  делать запросы пока пользователь не закроет приложение. Та и как то по-старинке еще осталась привычка экономить оперативку.

Comment: V.March, Уверяю, что в сервисе 5 секунд и даже 30 секунд не прокатит однозначно!