# Странное поведение Alarm Manager при попытке его закрыть

Tags: android, android-intent, android-alarm-manager

Я в цикле обновляю данные из интернета (пока что в цикле, потом перейду на более приемлемый вариант). Каждый раз, после обновления, я получаю список уведомлений, которые мне нужно вывести в определённое время (объект с уведомлением называется `Notification`, не путайте с Android'овскими уведомлениями). Чтобы вывести уведомления — я запускаю `AlarmManager` с периодичностью в пол секунды (потому что Android иногда делает погрешности, потом исправлю на более разумный вариант), чтобы он проверял, нужно ли вывести уведомления, а в `Intent` ему передаю сериаллизованный массив уведомлений.

Перед тем, как запустить установку новых уведомлений, я удаляю старые. Код выглядит так:

```
NotificationShower.stopNotifications(mContext);                             
NotificationShower.startNotifications(mContext, notifications);
```

Класс, который отвечает за уведомления выглядит так (только код, который имеет значение):

```
public class NotificationShower extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String TAG = "RLOG";
    public static final String EXTRA_NOTIFICATIONS_ARRAY = "notifications_array";

    ...

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String currentTime = dataFormat.format(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Log.i(TAG, "time = " + currentTime);

        Notification[] notifications = (Notification[]) intent.getExtras().getSerializable(EXTRA_NOTIFICATIONS_ARRAY);

        if (notifications == null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "notifications is null");
            return;
        }

        ...
    }

    ...
    ...
    ...

    public static void startNotifications(Context context, Notification[] notifications) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationShower.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NOTIFICATIONS_ARRAY, notifications);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(
                AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis() + 10 * 1000,
                30 * 1000,
                pendingIntent);
    }

    public static void stopNotifications(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationShower.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что, если вызвать метод `stopNotifications` перед `startNotifications` — в метод `onReceive` передаётся пустой `Intent`, который не содержит нужного мне массива! Без попытки остановки — работает нормально.

---

Я не могу понять, как это так связаны методы, что `.cancel` заставляет передаваться пустой `Intent`? В чем проблема, почему, после остановки и нового запуску, передаётся пустой `Intent`.

Comment: А если в cancel вместо FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT передать FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT ?

Comment: Таки да, должен быть Cancel. Вот тут проверенные методы запуска/отмены аларма: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/534643/17609

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, методом тыка я узнал, что ошибка была в отсутствии строки `pendingIntent.cancel();`...

Comment: Напишите это в ответ)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, нашел у Вас, так Вы и пишите :)).

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а Вы случайно не знаете, как заставить `ArarmManager` выполняться в нужное время?

Comment: @bukashka101, если вы о выполнении с точностью до секунды - то не знаю.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я себе вот такой вот класс написал — http://pastebin.com/C8GeRDKP. Наследуюсь, переопределяю метод `doAction()` и вставляю в нужных класс методом композиции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Должно помочь добавление отмены ещё и на `PendingIntent`

```
pendingIntent.cancel();
```

Также не лишним будет заменить  `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` на `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`