# Как реализовать уведомление в определённое время?

Tags: android, android-sdk

Приложение по типу планировщика задач. В базе данных хранятся задачи и необходимо реализовать напоминание в определённое время. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Вам нужен `AlarmManager`

Comment: Вот тут смотрите. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/534628/17609