# Как проложить маршрут на карте по расписанию с ArrayList

Tags: java, google-maps-api

Как проложить маршрут на карте по расписанию который хранится в `ArrayList`. У меня уже есть реализованные функции для прорисовки этого маршрута, нужно только вызвать их в определенное время по расписанию.

```
String url = getUrl(origin, dest);
                Log.d("onMapClick", url.toString());
                FetchUrl FetchUrl = new FetchUrl();

                // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                FetchUrl.execute(url);
```

Нужно вызвать эти функции в определенное время.

Comment: Мне кажется что эта простыня кода вообще не относится к вопросу. Ну уж процентов 90 точно. Попробуйте локализовать проблему. А то не понятно - вы хотите чтобы за вас код какой-то написали или в приведённом всё есть но оно не работает

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы совет дали на счет моей проблемы а код который написан 95% соответствует тому что должно быть

Comment: Лишнего кода слишком много. Он отпугивает большинство тех кто мог бы прочитать вопрос и попробовать вам помочь. Если данные вы уже получил - то код их получения к вопросу не относится. Так же как и всякие служебные вещи типа реализаций onResume/onPause и тем более пустые реализации интерфейсов типа onConnectionSuspended. Дайте шанс хоть попытаться понять где в вашем коде проблема. Если её нет в коде - то зачем код.

Comment: Думаю так лутше

Comment: Т.е. ваш вопрос про то как вызвать к-л метод автоматически с какой-то переодичностью или его надо вызывать в строго определённое время? Во время жизни приложения или даже после его отключения в фоновом режиме?

Comment: Его нужно вызывать в строго определённое время в беграунде.

Comment: Кажется вам нужен AlarmManager. Посмотрите код тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/534643/17609

Comment: Спасибо. Но мне нужно будет как-то проходиться циклом по списку с указанием времени вызова, если я правильно понял